# Android Studio 3.2.1: Endless Clean project

Tags: android-studio

I can't complete Clean or Build my app, because progress is endless and nothing happens. Tried to switch off my anti virus, but it takes no effect. Files → Invalidate Cached takes no effect too. Any suggestions?

Comment: Off top of my head.. file -> sync project gradle files

Comment: @teh_raab it seems this doesn't work for me

Comment: Sorry not sure then. I had this same issue a couple of weeks ago and syncing my project gradle from the file menu fixed it for me. Good luck!

Comment: As a result I had to reinstall my setup including gradle files (180K files, 3GB+ OMG)